# error: 'Date' does not name a type?

Tags: c++

i know this may be a simple problem, but i have been searching for hours and i cant solve it.
i stripped down the project to make it easier to find the problem, 
here's my code:

Date.h

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

Date{
  private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
  public:
    Date();
    Date(int, int, int)
};

#endif // DATE_H
```

Date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date(){
   day = 0;
   month = 0;
   year = 0;
}


Date::Date(int day, int month, int year){
   this->day = day;
   this->month = month;
   this->year = year;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Date d1(14, 2, 15);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you missed `class` keyword before `Date`?

Comment: i knew it was something stupid, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Date.h` you missed the `class` keyword in front of the declaration.

Comment: Also there should be a semicolon after `Date(int, int, int)`